# How to move and append next row to previous row in the Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can you please help for formatting the pandas dataframe, I want to move and append the next row in dataframe to the previous row. Below example -

[Original DataFrame -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAQBb.png)

[Required Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKtwI.png)

Thanks..!!

Comment: add the code inline instead of images. follow https://app.cedreo.com/#/activation/bW5hdmVlZEBvdXRsb29rLmNvbQ1BMzcwMUZFMDZFODVEQjZGNjkwMTQ2M0JDODA2QTY0Mw%3D%3D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Was able to handle it as below -

Separate the dataframe based on the type and then merge as below -

```
a_df = df[df['type'] =='A']
b_df = df[df['type'] == 'B']
merged = a_df.merge(b_df, how='outer', on='data')
```

Thanks..!!